# CakePHP: Accessing post data in AppController::beforeFilter

Tags: php, cakephp, post, cakephp-2.3, before-filter

I am using CakePHP 2.3.4.

I found that the post data (`$this->request->data`) is not ready in `AppController::beforeFilter`. It is only available when routed to the action methods (e.g. `UserController::login`).

I found that the post data is available after the `Controller::startupProcess` where it dispatch a `CakeEvent`:

```
$this->getEventManager()->dispatch(new CakeEvent('Controller.startup', $this));
```

But I cannot make this call in my `AppController::beforeFilter` as it will let the program free run. Is there is a way to make the post data available in `AppController::beforeFilter`?

Comment: Your code isn't in the question, your problem is unclear. `the post data ($this->request->data) is not ready in AppController::beforeFilter` at face value that is not true - the request object [is set on construction](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L337) - For the lifetime of a controller the request object doesn't change, it's not a different or modified request object between the beforeFilter and the action - it's the same object with the same data. You are currently looking at/describing the wrong problem, probably.

Comment: @AD7six I can see that the request object is set on construction. Actually, the problem is not the request object but the request data instead. The request data is not set until the 'Controller.startup' CakeEvent is fired. I have read many other posts that they did show an evidence that the request data is set in the beforeFilter function. I wonder why my code is behaving differently. Thanks!

Comment: `the problem is not the request object but the request data instead` - That's the same thing. `I have read many other posts [...]` please link to them by editing the question. Please **demonstrate a problem** don't describe it, your description doesn't fit expected behavior, so at the very least it's not obvious why/what is happening and suggests bad debugging/a misunderstanding. The purpose of my first comment is to prompt you to debug/provide more info - not repeat the question in a comment.